# SQL Server - Update several columns in table when the join's where clause has conditions that are mutually exclusive

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code so far:

```
update 
    A
set 
    A.NAME= B.NAME,
    A.MOBILE = C.MOBILE
    A.TOLLFREE = C.NUMBERVALUE 
from ACCOUNT A
    inner join COMPANY B on a.COMPANYID = B.COMPANYID
    inner join PHONE C on B.COMPANYID = C.COMPANYID
where c.TYPEID = '1111'
```

The idea is that C.TYPEID has several codes.

- 1111 is the tollfree phone
- 2222 is the mobile phone

I'd like to write a single statement updating all the different phone column types where the `C.TypeID` is 1111 for the toll free phones and `C.TYPEID` is 2222 for the mobile phones.

How would I do that?

Comment: If you want to update for multiple `C.TYPEID` and want to use the same update query; why don't you remove WHERE clause or change it to `where c.TYPEID  in ('1111'  ,'2222')`

Answer (score 0):

if your update value is same for both record then you just need to change the where condition your update statement as below

```
update 
A
set 
A.NAME= B.NAME,
A.MOBILE = C.MOBILE
A.TOLLFREE = C.NUMBERVALUE 
from ACCOUNT A
inner join COMPANY B on a.COMPANYID = B.COMPANYID
inner join PHONE C on B.COMPANYID = C.COMPANYID
where c.TYPEID in ('1111', ' 2222')
```

Note:  this good only  if the value you are updating hold good for both TypeID.

Thanks

Comment: The TYPEID column value indicates in the PHONE table what type of phone number it is.  So I want to update A.Mobile (a phone number indicated in the PHONE table with the TYPEID '2222' ) and I want to update the A.TollFree (a phone number indicated in the PHONE table with the TYPEID '1111').  The two phone numbers are different.

Comment: Hmmm  i have the below wired method , am not sure whether this is the best way to right it but it will definitely fulfil your requirement                      **update 
A
set 
A.NAME= B.NAME,
A.MOBILE = (select C.MOBILE from  PHONE C join Account a on B.COMPANYID = C.COMPANYID where Typeid='1111')
A.TOLLFREE = (select  C.NUMBERVALUE from  PHONE C join Account a on B.COMPANYID = C.COMPANYID where Typeid='2222')
from ACCOUNT A
inner join COMPANY B on a.COMPANYID = B.COMPANYI**